# How to make a juju relation between rails and mongodb?

Tags: juju, rails, mongodb

The juju charm of mongodb does have support for which relations?
Is possible to make a relation between rails and mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the `Requires` section of the [charm's web page](http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/rails):

[image]

So unfortunately at this time the Rails charm only supports mysql, which is a shame because the mongodb charm is [pretty sophisticated](http://blog.xtremeghost.com/2012/11/lets-shard-something.html).

We'd need someone to add mongodb support to the charm via hooks, and there need to be relation hooks in mongodb for rails, the documentation on how to do that is [here](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charm-store.html#submitting-a-fix-to-an-existing-charm).

I have an interest in getting as many databases supported in the Rails charm as possible, but unfortunately Rails expertise in Ubuntu itself is usually shorthanded, if you or anyone is interested in working on it please ping me directly via my [contact information](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro).

Comment: I will ping you for get start learning how to do this and maybe I can add this support.